# Train data selection for model comparison

Tags: regression, neural-networks, model-comparison

Let I have data to compare two models.

- My first model wil be based on Arificial Neural Network(ANN)
- My second model will based on linear regression(LR)

For the ANN, I have to divide data into 3 parts:

- Train data
- Validation data
- Test data

For LR, I have to divide data into 2 parts(since I dont need Validation data):

- Train data
- Test data

And finaly I will compare performance two models using test data.

But, I am confused how should I select Train data for LR.

I mean for LR, should be same train data of ANN. Or should it consist of both Validation data of ANN and train data of ANN.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An Apples to apples comparison will see two models trained on the same amount of data.  To select between your linear model and your neural network, you will use the validation set (which means whatever set you use as validation for your network, you have to use the same set for your linear model).

The model with the lowest loss on the validation set is likely the model you will choose.  From there, you use the selected model on the test set to get a final estimate of out of sample performance.  You touch the test set once and only once.

Comment: What would you validate with the linear model? Variable selection? Ridge/LASSO/elastic net hyperparemeters? It sounds like the OP would just fit the $\hat{\beta}_{ols} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ and then predict out-of-sample.

Comment: @Dave The validation set is used for model selection.  Train the network and the linear model on the train set.  Which model is better?  Use the validation set to answer that.  This sort of data splitting is not preferable (see Harrell's RMS book for more) but unless OP wants to cross validate a neural network this would be the most straight forward way to compare the two.

Comment: I need Validation data set only for ANN for determining the optimum hyper parameters. But I dont need Validation data for LR. Models will be compared using test data. So I am confused. Test data is ok. They will be similar. But what about Train data. For ANN obvious. The determined Train data. But i am confused with the Train data for LR. Should that include the Validation data of ANN.

Comment: @oercim The models should not be compared using the test set.  The entire point of the test set is to provide an out of sample estimate of performance which is not influenced by any other information (like a different model's performance on the same data).  What your proposing is wrong -- benignly so, but ultimately wrong.

Comment: @Demetri Pananos I want to mean that, by validation stage I select the parameter tuned ANN. That is my first model. Then I model LR. This second model. Then by using same test data(out of sample) I compare their performance. Is this wrong. I am confused.